# Java | How can I create a list from a json using JsonPath RestAssured?

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, jsonpath

I have the following json and want to create a list from the display names, the json can have many different types not necessarily only 2:

```
{"data": [
  {
  "types": {
    "1": {
    "display_name": "123",
    },
    "2": {
    "display_name": "321",
    },
  }
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
JsonPath json = response.jsonPath();
List<String> list = json.getList("data.types.*.display_name");
```

to get the display names, I can easily replace the "*" with "1" or "2" but I don't know what the name of the types will be (not necessarily 1 or 2, could be any string).

I want to create a list of strings from all of the display names in the json.

Answer (score 0):

I think [JsonPath jayway](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) is better in this case. The code would be

```java
@Test
public void test76514033() {
    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"data\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"types\": {\n" +
            "        \"1\": {\n" +
            "          \"display_name\": \"123\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"2\": {\n" +
            "          \"display_name\": \"321\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";

    List<String> names =  com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(json, "$.data..display_name");
    System.out.println(names);  //["123","321"]
}
```